# Why does MPMusicPlayerController call its now playing item changed selector method twice? 

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, media-player, mpmusicplayercontroller

> I am writing a music playlist editing application for the iPhone.
>
> I am subscribing to the `MPMusicPlayerController`
>   `MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification`and I am
>   getting a problem where the `@selector` method for this notification
>   is being called more than once when the `nowPlayingItem:` changes.

I have divided up each playlist into their own `MPMediaItemCollection` objets, and when one playlist is finished I load the next one, by calling `-pause` on the player, passing a new `MPMediaItemCollection`to the music player controller via its `-setQueueWithItemCollection:` method. I then explicitly set the nowPlayingItem to an item of item of my own and finally I call `-play`.

```
        [musicPlayer pause];
        [musicPlayer setQueueWithItemCollection:[MPMediaItemCollection collectionWithItems:[selectedPrefs mediaItems]]];
        musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem = [selectedPrefs.playbackItems objectAtIndex:selectedPrefs.nowPlayingIndex];
        [musicPlayer play];
```

When I do this the `@selector` is called twice for the now playing item changing. I suspect this is because `-setQueueWithItemCollection:`automatically changes the now playing item to point to the first media item in the new collection, and then I am changing this item again before calling `-play`.

Many thanks.

Comment: I've noticed something similar, but haven't had time to look into it yet.  Curious what you'll find.

Comment: Yeah I have still not been able to get to the bottom of this, it is highly frustrating. Will let you know my findings if I have any. Cheers.

Comment: It's been this way for years. I've filed a bug. Feel free to do the same!

Comment: IOS 10.2 still the same, it creates two distinct NSConcreteNotifications.
Shame on you apple.